# Why "Extend volume" in Windows 7 is greyed out?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I want to extend C: drive in my Windows 7 PC which is the primary partition. I converted its adjacent D: drive into primary partition which was initially a logical partition. But the problem is that I am unable to extend C: by merging both C: and D:, because in ***windows disk management*** when I right-click C:, the ***extend volume*** feature is greyed out. Why is it happening and what should I do? I am also giving an image of my partitions herewith.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't (directly) merge 2 partitions. The "Extend Volume" option is greyed out because it has no available space adjacent to the partition, making C bigger would overlap with D, which is a full fledged partition (it is just empty, but that does not matter, that space is reserved for it anyways).

The solution is to *delete* the volume D, and apply changes, so that region of the disk becomes unallocated space instead.

In any case, there are some changes that you cannot do to a partition when booting from it. The easiest solution for this problem is to just use a live SO that does not need to make use of the partition you want to modify, like the open source utility gparted: https://gparted.org/ (you can burn a bootable CD/USB to use this utility)

Comment: You can do this from windows. Only removing a partition in use would not be possible, but because D is not a system partition, this can be fully done from within windows.

Comment: Resizing Windows partitions by Linux is not a good idea. Windows Disk Manager should be able to handle everything.

Comment: @lgb  Thank you so much, I just deleted the volume first and then merged them both by simply extending volume in windows disk management.